# Expiry links in Azure API management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am a bit new to azure and API management concepts. With the help of Doc's I have integrated azure function with API.

Is there anyway that I can have expiry links in API management i.e., a link with specific parameters should expire after 2 hours.

Comment: Please elborate on the question,  what links need expiry?

Answer (score 0):

There's no ready to use functionality for that. The easiest way would be schedule the execution of an Azure Function and call the API Management REST Api to delete the endpoint:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/apis/delete